# what is the difference between C, cc, and S commands in vim

Tags: vim

They seems to erase the line and enter the insertion mode.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

- `C` replaces the rest of the line (starting at cursor position) with your edit.
- `cc` and `S` are synonyms and replace the whole line(s) with your edit.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have `cl` or `cil` to change the line?

Comment: @ThomasAhle, `cl` would make sense if `l` jumped to the next line, I think. But since `l`' goes to the next character I don't think it would make sense.

Comment: @ThomasAhle I made 'inside line' and 'around line' text objects  so `cil`, `dil`, `yil` (and the `cal` counterparts...etc.) all work:

`onoremap <silent> il :<C-u>normal! ^vg_<CR>` and `onoremap <silent> al :<C-u>normal! 0v$<CR>`

Answer (score 26):

From `:h C`...

> Delete from the cursor position to the end of the
>               line [...] and
>               start insert.  Synonym for `c$`.

And `:h S` gives us...

> Delete [count] lines [...] and start
>               insert.  Synonym for `cc`.